# Parallel folder size scanning. WaitAll() hangs

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await, task

I think I get that this is hanging because I am not awaiting the async call from Main causing a deadlock but I cant make Main async so how to fix this? I will first show the program I am trying to parallelize then I will show my attempt at parallelization. I think it is obvious I am trying to get the fastest possible program to check the size of a list of folders (from multiple shares). If it is possible to parallelize at a higher level and write the outputs to CSV out of order that is fine but I was satisfied with processing one share at a time. I have tried several derivations of the parallel code. This is just my latest so it is possible it is more wrong than my earlier attempts. Just know that this was not my only attempt. I am currently knee deep in researching parallelization in c# and will probably be able to figure this out at some point but if you can offer insights that would be greatly appreciated

```
namespace ShareSize
{
    class Program
    {
        static long Size { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(args[0]))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    share = sr.ReadLine().Trim(',');
                    Console.WriteLine(share);
                    string[] root = Directory.GetDirectories(share);
                    MeasureFolders(root);
                    MeasureFiles(Directory.GetFiles(share));
                    Console.WriteLine("SIZE = " + Size);
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(args[1], true))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(share + "," + Size / 1073741824);
                    }
                    Size = 0;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static MeasureFolders(string[] root)
        {
            MeasureFolder(root);
        }

        private static MeasureFolder(string[] directories)
        {
            foreach (string d in directories)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Measure Folder {d}");
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(d);
                    string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(d);
                    if (files.Length != 0)
                        MeasureFiles(files);
                    if (subDirectories.Length != 0)
                        MeasureFolder(subDirectories);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void MeasureFiles(string[] files)
        {
            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                Size += new FileInfo(f).Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my attempt at parallelization.

```
    namespace ShareSize
    {
        class Program
        {
        static long Size { get; set; }

        static List<Task> Tasks = new List<Task>();

        private static Object Lock = new Object();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            string share = "";
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(args[0]))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    share = sr.ReadLine().Trim(',');
                    string[] root = Directory.GetDirectories(share);
                    MeasureFolders(root).ConfigureAwait(false);                   
                    MeasureFiles(Directory.GetFiles(share));
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(args[1], true))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(share + "," + Size / 1073741824);
                    }
                    Size = 0;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task MeasureFolders(string[] root)
        {
            await MeasureFolder(root).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await Task.WhenAll(Tasks.ToArray());
        }

        private static async Task MeasureFolder(string[] directories)
        {
            foreach (string d in directories)
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(d);
                    string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(d);
                    if (files.Length != 0)
                    {
                        Task newTask = new Task(delegate { MeasureFiles(files); });
                        newTask.Start();
                        Tasks.Add(newTask);
                    }
                    if (subDirectories.Length != 0)
                        await MeasureFolder(subDirectories);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ;
                }

            }
        }

        private static void MeasureFiles(string[] files)
        {
            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                lock (Lock)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Size += new FileInfo(f).Length;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: On a side note: never use `new Task`. Use `Task.Run` instead. Although here there isn’t any need for either as MeasureFiles is just a summation which is much faster than instantiating the task - so your code got slower by running it in a task. Also a task wouldn’t helped you anyway as you lock every summation, so the code couldn’t run in parallel tasks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I am missing the point, but the above seems a bit over-complicated. The below code snippets get the directory size of any given path. I wrote the code in such a way that comparing the serialized code to the parallelized code is easier. But one of the biggest things to consider: If you are going to collect data in parallel, you will likely need to allocate memory ahead of time (array), or lock the object to ensure no concurrent access (lock() { }). Both are demonstrated below.

Notes:

- This code can be optimized further
- Getting the size on disk would require a few changes
- This uses built-in C# `Parallel.For`, `Parallel.Foreach`, and `lock() {}` syntax

### SerialFunctions

```
    public long GetDirectorySizesBytes(string root) {
        long dirsize = 0;
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(root);

        if (files != null) {
            dirsize += GetFileSizesBytes(files);
        }

        foreach(var dir in directories) {
            var size = GetDirectorySizesBytes(dir);

            dirsize += size;
        }

        return dirsize;

    }

    public long GetFileSizesBytes(string[] files) {
        long[] fileSizes = new long[files.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
            fileSizes[i] = new FileInfo(files[i]).Length;
        }

        return fileSizes.Sum();
    }
```

### Parallelized Functions

```
    public long ParallelGetDirectorySizesBytes(string root) {
        long dirsize = 0;
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(root);

        if (files != null) {
            dirsize += ParallelGetFileSizesBytes(files);
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(directories, dir => {
            var size = ParallelGetDirectorySizesBytes(dir);
            lock (lockObject) {  //static lockObject defined at top of class
                dirsize += size;
            }
        });

        return dirsize;

    }

    public long ParallelGetFileSizesBytes(string[] files) {
        long[] fileSizes = new long[files.Length];
        Parallel.For(0, files.Length, i => {
            fileSizes[i] = new FileInfo(files[i]).Length;
        });


        return fileSizes.Sum();
    }
```

### Test function

```
[TestMethod]
    public void GetDirectoriesSizesTest() {
        var actual = GetDirectorySizesBytes(@"C:\Exchanges");
        var parallelActual = ParallelGetDirectorySizesBytes(@"C:\Exchanges");

        long expected = 25769767281;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, parallelActual);
    }
```

### Complete Class

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflowProjects.Tests {
[TestClass]
public class DirectorySizeTests {

    public static object lockObject = new object();
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetDirectoriesSizesTest() {
        var actual = GetDirectorySizesBytes(@"C:\Exchanges");
        var parallelActual = ParallelGetDirectorySizesBytes(@"C:\Exchanges");

        long expected = 25769767281;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, parallelActual);
    }

    public long GetDirectorySizesBytes(string root) {
        long dirsize = 0;
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(root);

        if (files != null) {
            dirsize += GetFileSizesBytes(files);
        }

        foreach(var dir in directories) {
            var size = GetDirectorySizesBytes(dir);

            dirsize += size;
        }

        return dirsize;

    }

    public long GetFileSizesBytes(string[] files) {
        long[] fileSizes = new long[files.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
            fileSizes[i] = new FileInfo(files[i]).Length;
        }

        return fileSizes.Sum();
    }

    public long ParallelGetDirectorySizesBytes(string root) {
        long dirsize = 0;
        string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(root);

        if (files != null) {
            dirsize += ParallelGetFileSizesBytes(files);
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(directories, dir => {
            var size = ParallelGetDirectorySizesBytes(dir);
            lock (lockObject) {
                dirsize += size;
            }
        });

        return dirsize;

    }

    public long ParallelGetFileSizesBytes(string[] files) {
        long[] fileSizes = new long[files.Length];
        Parallel.For(0, files.Length, i => {
            fileSizes[i] = new FileInfo(files[i]).Length;
        });


        return fileSizes.Sum();
    }


    }
}
```